# DFA Minimization Brzozowski algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, dfa, nfa, automaton

I am trying to implement Brzozowski's algorithm for minimizing my DFA
Following is the algorithm for the same.

```
DFA = d(r(d(r(NFA))))
```

where `r()` is reversal of NFA and `D()` converts NFA to DFA.

But I do not understand what is the meaning of `r()` searching on google also does not gives much information.

Can anybody please explain what is `r()` of NFA.

Any other simple algorithm or C++ implementation available please let me know the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code for reverse.c (found <s>[here](http://elide.org/libfsm/browser/trunk/src/libfsm/reverse.c?rev=40)</s>, but now defunct) you'll find a comment `/* Create reversed edges */`. So I'd say that `r()` is reversing the direction of all edges (plus making sure that the reversed automaton has a well defined start state).

Comment: I did looked at your blog before putting a question. Could you please help me to understand what is conceptually reverse of NFA means. Does it means if there is transition from State S1 to S2 , it become S2 to S1 and what happens to all the Final and non-final states.

Comment: it's not my blog, but yes, the impression I get from the code is exactly what you say. And when looking at the `case` statement after `/* Create the new start state */`, I get the impression that the code (reverse.c) creates a new start state and connects it to all end states of the original NFA via an epsilon transition.

Comment: What happens with the Final and non-final state.

Answer (score 3):

### Brzozowski's algorithm

Brzozowski's algorithm is clearer written as:

```
minimized_DFA = subset(reverse(subset(reverse(NFA))))
```

where `subset` denotes subset construction (also known as [powerset construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction)). Subset construction builds a DFA by simulating all transitions for each equivalent set of states (due to epsilon transitions) in the NFA.

Reversing an NFA involves these steps:

1. Reverse the direction of all transition edges in the NFA.
2. Create a new starting state that has epsilon transitions to all accepting states in the NFA.
3. Mark all accepting states as non-accepting in the NFA.
4. Make the old starting state the new accepting state.

Steps 2-4 effectively swaps the roles of accepting and starting states.

---

### Brzozowski's algorithm example

Here's an example of minimizing a DFA based on a [Udacity quiz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uMrPCrJ1pRI) for a compilers course (the steps are the same with an NFA as initial input).

#### Initial DFA:

[image: initial DFA]

This DFA accepts strings like `{"", "a", "aa", "aaa", "aaabba", "ba", "bab", "ababa", "ababb"}` and rejects strings like `{"b", "ab", "aab", "aabb", "bb", "bbb"}`. In other words, it rejects strings that have a `"b"` unless they also have a `"ba"` substring. It's pretty obvious that `s1`-`s3` and `s2`-`s4` are redundant.

#### Step 1: `reverse(DFA)`:

[image: reverse(DFA)]

#### Step 2: `subset(reverse(DFA))`:

Run subset construction to build a table of DFA states to represent possible transitions from each unique epsilon closure (`^` denotes a start state, `$` denotes an accepting state):

```
A = e-closure({s5}) = {s0,s2,s4}
B = e-closure({s0,s1,s2,s3,s4}) = {s0,s1,s2,s3,s4}
C = e-closure({s2,s4}) = {s2,s4}
D = e-closure({s1,s2,s3,s4}) = {s1,s2,s3,s4}

     a   b
-----------
A^$  B   C
B$   B   B
C    D   C
D    D   B
```

[image: subset(reverse(DFA))]

#### Step 3: `reverse(subset(reverse(DFA)))`:

Reverse the DFA. After eliminating common prefixes, another pass enables elimination of common suffixes.

[image: reverse(subset(reverse(DFA)))]

#### Step 4: `subset(reverse(subset(reverse(DFA))))`:

Run subset construction one more time to minimize the NFA.

```
A = e-closure({E}) = {A,B}
B = e-closure({B,D}) = {B,D}
C = e-closure({A,B,C,D} = {A,B,C,D}

    a  b
--------
A^$ A  B
B   C  B
C$  C  C
```

[image: subset(reverse(subset(reverse(DFA))))]

---

#### References:

- Engineering a Compiler by Cooper and Torczon, 2nd edition. Subset construction is described on page 49 and Brzozowski's algorithm is on page 75.
- [Udacity's Compilers: Theory and Practice course](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud168), lesson 3.

#### Graphviz code for above diagrams:

```
// initial DFA
digraph G {
    rankdir=LR;
    size="8,5"
    
    node [shape=point]; qi;
    node [shape=doublecircle]; s0 s2 s4;
    node [shape=circle];

    qi -> s0;
    s0 -> s0 [label="a"];
    s0 -> s1 [label="b"];
    s1 -> s2 [label="a"];
    s2 -> s2 [label="a"];
    s2 -> s4 [label="b"];
    s4 -> s4 [label="a,b"];
    s1 -> s3 [label="b"];
    s3 -> s3 [label="b"];
    s3 -> s2 [label="a"];
}
```

```
// reverse(DFA)
digraph G {
    rankdir=LR;
    size="8,5"
    
    node [shape=point]; qi;
    node [shape=doublecircle]; s0;
    node [shape=circle];

    qi -> s5;
    s0 -> s0 [label="a"];
    s1 -> s0 [label="b"];
    s2 -> s1 [label="a"];
    s2 -> s2 [label="a"];
    s4 -> s2 [label="b"];
    s4 -> s4 [label="a,b"];
    s3 -> s1 [label="b"];
    s3 -> s3 [label="b"];
    s2 -> s3 [label="a"];
    s5 -> s2 [label="e"];
    s5 -> s0 [label="e"];
    s5 -> s4 [label="e"];
}
```

```
// subset(reverse(DFA))
digraph G {
    rankdir=LR;
    size="8,5"
    
    node [shape=point]; qi;
    node [shape=doublecircle]; A B;
    node [shape=circle];

    qi -> A;
    A -> B [label="a"];
    A -> C [label="b"];
    B -> B [label="a,b"];
    D -> B [label="b"];
    C -> D [label="a"];
    C -> C [label="b"];
    D -> D [label="a"];
}
```

```
// reverse(subset(reverse(DFA)))
digraph G {
    rankdir=LR;
    size="8,5"
    
    node [shape=point]; qi;
    node [shape=doublecircle]; A;
    node [shape=circle];

    qi -> E;
    B -> A [label="a"];
    C -> A [label="b"];
    B -> B [label="a,b"];
    B -> D [label="b"];
    D -> C [label="a"];
    C -> C [label="b"];
    D -> D [label="a"];
    E -> A [label="e"];
    E -> B [label="e"];
}
```

```
// subset(reverse(subset(reverse(DFA))))
digraph G {
    rankdir=LR;
    size="8,5"
    
    node [shape=point]; qi;
    node [shape=doublecircle]; A C;
    node [shape=circle];

    qi -> A;
    A -> A [label="a"];
    A -> B [label="b"];
    B -> B [label="b"];
    B -> C [label="a"];
    C -> C [label="a,b"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://openfst.cs.nyu.edu/doxygen/fst/html/reverse_8h_source.html)  is the implementation from OpenFst.

In [this](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~mohri/pub/hwa.pdf) paper is a  diagram (page 15)  that show results of applying the reverse operation.

An easier way to help understand FSM operations is to use a library like OpenFst to create and manipulable the machines and  then visualize the results using  Graphviz.